# Data-Icons not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get a button to work with a data-icon, according to 
"http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html"
It should be a case of writing the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <link href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <a data-role="button" href="#page1" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">
        Button
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I build this locally and deploy on a server it does not show an icon.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: your `<link>`tag should be between your `<head>`tags. Don't know if this causes the error though.

Answer (score 3):

Your markup should look like this.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then jQuery Mobile code

```
<div data-role='page'>
 <a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-u' data-iconpos='left'>Button</a>
</div>
```

References:

- [jQuery Mobile CDN](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)
- [jQuery Mobile Buttons](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/buttons/#button-icon-position)

Answer (score 0):

see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqebut/1/)

you need to put <link> tag inside head content and also, you might need to add some other(below) scripts too.

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style sheet needs to be linked in the head.

```
<head>
   <title></title>
   <link href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <a data-role="button" href="#page1" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">
    Button
   </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your link tag to head section. And according to your link to css file,

```
You must also include JQM's images folder under your "Content/" folder.
```

Your html code must look like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    ...content goes here...
</body>
</html>
```